# Angular JS - Sortable table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, sortablejs

I'm developing a project in AngularJS but I'm having several difficulties to sort the columns in my table. I've tried so many ways and javascript librarys but the data in the table is dynamic so nothing has worked so far. Can someone give me an idea of ​​how to try for my case? Thanks in advance :) 
Here is my table:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-dark table-bordered" id="tabela">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="headers" ng-repeat="header in headers track by $index"">{{header}}</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>  
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
                <td class="tbody" ng-repeat="data in row track by $index">{{data}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: Look at https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome (AngularJS version)

Comment: @davidkonrad thank you, i will analise this documentation.

Comment: I found one of my old plunkrs -> http://plnkr.co/edit/XpBcLhlm0Frq3voN6X97?p=preview&preview